# How to Convert NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In objective c how to convert `NSMutableArray` to `NSMutableDictionary` I tried with this code.but only last index object only adding in the dictionary.
I need the format like this

```
ADDRESS =
{
    major = 604;
    minor = 37940;
    uuid = "xxxxxxx";
};
{
    major = 604;
    minor = 37940;
    uuid = "xxxxxxxxx";
};
 {
    major = 604;
    minor = 37940;
    uuid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
};
```

I tried with this code

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int j = 0; j <[self.beaconListArray count]; j ++)

{
    [dic1 setObject:[self.beaconListArray objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"ADDRESS"];

}
```

Comment: In dictionary, there is UNICITY of the key. From the doc of `setObject:forKey:`: `If aKey already exists in the dictionary, anObject takes its place.` What you want seems to be `[dic1 setObject:self.beaconListArray forKey:@"ADDRESS"];`

Comment: which key you want to store

Comment: ohh...you have to save with different keys not only one key as "ADDRESS". You can save as 

[dic1 setObject:[self.beaconListArray objectAtIndex:j] forKey:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"ADDRESS%d",j]];

Comment: the key is  not already in the dictionary an adding the key for identification of an array

Comment: My original Concern is i have  dictionary of data in my hand.i want to post this Using Restkit.
    ""ADDRESS{
        major = 604;
        minor = 37940;
        uuid = "xxxxxx";
    }, {major = 1;
        minor = 4541;
        uuid = "xxxxx";
    },{ major = 20310;
        minor = 48417;
        uuid = "xxxx";}, 
i passed this data using RestKit but in the server side it getting like this
 {
    "ADDRESS": [
        {"major": "604"
        }, 
        {
        "minor": "37940"
        }, 
        {
            "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },

Answer (score 2):

Try like this , Because you're dictionary is overiding object and you have already array of your data and you need to create dictionary using that for address key

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dic1 setObject:self.beaconListArray forKey:@"ADDRESS"];
```

Comment: i need data in a dictionary not in an array. you are adding array in to an array
[tmpArray setObject:tmpArray forKey:@"ADDRESS"];

Comment: it'll convert in dictionary and all array data will save on "ADDRESS" key

Comment: My original Concern is i have dictionary of data in my hand.i want to post this Using Restkit. ""ADDRESS{ major = 604; minor = 37940; uuid = "xxxxxx"; }, {major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxx"; },{ major = 20310; minor = 48417; uuid = "xxxx";}, i passed this data using RestKit but in the server side it getting like this { "ADDRESS": [ {"major": "604" }, { "minor": "37940" }, { "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },

Comment: @Manju .. Yes its right .. because in server side its showing in json format

Comment: server side data need like this, is any issue am passing the data

 {
        major = 1;
        minor = 4541;
        uuid = "20CAE8A0-A9CF-11E3-A5E2-0800200C9A66";
    },

Comment: @Manju no issue

Comment: Can u please help me to get same format in server side also

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
dic1[@"ADDRESS"] = self.beaconListArray;
```

Comment: My original Concern is i have dictionary of data in my hand.i want to post this Using Restkit. ""ADDRESS{ major = 604; minor = 37940; uuid = "xxxxxx"; }, {major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxx"; },{ major = 20310; minor = 48417; uuid = "xxxx";}, i passed this data using RestKit but in the server side it getting like this { "ADDRESS": [ {"major": "604" }, { "minor": "37940" }, { "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }, server side data need like this, is any issue am passing the data { major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxxxx"; },

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to this code** 
 **Dictionary**

```
  NSMutableDictionary * dic1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

**Add Dictionary to array with key**

```
[dic1 setObject:self.beaconListArray forKey:@"ADDRESS"];
```

**Print Dictionary**

```
 NSLog(@"dic1====: %@",dic1);
```

Comment: My original Concern is i have dictionary of data in my hand.i want to post this Using Restkit. ""ADDRESS{ major = 604; minor = 37940; uuid = "xxxxxx"; }, {major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxx"; },{ major = 20310; minor = 48417; uuid = "xxxx";}, i passed this data using RestKit but in the server side it getting like this { "ADDRESS": [ {"major": "604" }, { "minor": "37940" }, { "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
server side data need like this, is any issue am passing the data { major = 1; minor = 4541; uuid = "xxxxxxx"; },